# Have you seen this PDE before?

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

Consider the second-order nonlinear PDE

$$(\partial_x\partial_y\varphi)\cdot\varphi = \partial_x\varphi\,\partial_y\varphi.$$

This PDE is solved by all ('separable') functions $\varphi\in C^2(\Omega)$ of the form $\varphi(x,y) = \ell(x)\cdot r(y)$ (any $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$ open).

I'd like to know whether each (classical) solution of the PDE is of this form.

Are you aware of any 'uniqueness' results for the above PDE which might (dis)prove this?

Comment: This equation is equivalent to $\partial_x \partial_y \log(\varphi) = 0$. This is the 2-dimensional wave equation for $\log(\varphi)$ in "null" coordinates.

Comment: That settles it, thanks. @IgorKhavkine

Comment: @fsp-b Not completely: it shows that it is true for positive solutions, but since the equation has compactly supported solutions, you can combine them to form solutions that aren't (globally) separable.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment, @MartinHairer I in fact happen to be interested in positive solutions only, so for me, this in fact gives what I needed.